# Setting up ipv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

My ISP (Charter) offers a 6RD relay to IPv6. I'd like to configure Ubuntu to use that address. Most of the links I am finding are how to disable IPv6. So I'm not sure how to get it working. I found a blog on the interface file and modified mine to include IPv6:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#Initalize the main interface
auto eth0
#set the static information here
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.103
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    gateway 192.168.1.1
#Initalize the eth0 with ipv6
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

I think I need a way to point to the 6rd relay. But I'm not sure where I can put that.

Charter's information:

```
6rd Prefix = 2602:100::/32
Border Relay Address = 68.114.165.1
6rd prefix length = 32
IPv4 mask length = 0
Primary DNS Address = 2607:f428:1::5353:1 
Secondary DNS Address = 2607:f428:2::5353:1
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a router via IPv4 at 192.168.1.1 Does your router support IPv6?

Comment: yes.  I have a wrt54g  Running dd-wrt standard   
DD-WRT


Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (11/02/09) std

Comment: That might be too old. The WRT54G is ancient, and DD-WRT is also quite old.

Comment: It looks like DD-WRT versions prior to 2010 didn't support IPv6. However it looks like Exact DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/08/11) std-nokaid (SVN revision 17990M NEWD-2 Eko) does. To get this back on topic, What are the results you get when you visit http://test-ipv6.charter.com/ ?

Comment: You need to configure 6rd on the IPv4 address provided by your ISP. Configuring 6rd on a host behind your own NAT device is probably not going to work. Running 6rd behind a CGN is however a fully supported configuration, so if the ISP hasn't given you a public IP on the outside of your router, 6rd can still work. It may be better for you to configure 6rd on the router rather than on the Ubuntu machine. Notice that 6in4 and 6rd are similar enough, that if a device happens to only support one of them, you can still make it work by tweaking the settings accordingly.

Comment: A side note.  Do not set `broadcast` and `network`, as the computer calculates them correctly from `address` and `netmask` anyway if not set.  That is usually a better choice, as it's too easy to get them wrong and then the network will not work.

Comment: You have an example here: http://serverfault.com/questions/402903/debian-6rd-tunnel-and-connection-troubles

Comment: I have seen that `OpenWRT` have support for 6RD and runs well on the WRT54G.

Comment: Three years later and those idiots are still using 6rd? Anyway, this isn't about Ubuntu, but about your WRT54G. You'll have better luck on [su].

Comment: Why this aggression against using 6RD? Please explain @Michael Hampton. See RFC 5969.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so firmware for routers is off-topic here as well. However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at this stuff, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: This question is sort of obsolete as Charter (now Spectrum) finally got rid of 6rd and is doing native dual stack like they should have all along. And of course it's still not about Ubuntu and should have been closed long ago on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

[6rd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_rapid_deployment) needs to originate from a router with a global, routeable IPv4 address. You can't run 6rd *across* a NAT device; it needs to run from the edge of the network since the tunnel encodes a globally routable IPv4 border relay. This allows fully stateless tunneling, but precludes the use of RFC1918 addressed tunnel endpoints (border relays).

Unless the Ubuntu device is acting as a router with a global IPv4 address, this will not work. You need a router that supports 6rd at the network edge.

Answer (score 0):

Comecast have explained how to use OpenWRT to set up 6RD.  It might be usefull for you to try it out, as they uses similar hardware as you are, but with OpenWRT firmware.
http://www.comcast6.net/index.php/6rd-config